# What NamedDecl in clang contain?

Tags: clang, llvm, clang++

How can I know that **clang::NamedDecl** contains identifier of function?
I have pointer on **clang::NamedDecl**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isa` or `dyn_cast`, e.g.

```
if (FunctionDecl *F = dyn_cast<FunctionDecl>(myNamedDecl)) {
    // use F
}
```

Comment: Using that method i have some nodes which correspond your condition for one function. Why this happened? Because dyn_cast triggered also on ValueDecl and DeclaratorDecl?

Comment: @spiridoncha I don't understand your question.

Comment: I just don't know how to speak well in English. But I had already decided my problem. Thank you for the answer.